# What's the best way to convert between PDF, HTML, and presentation formats in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'd like to find an effective and efficient way to convert between PDF, HTML, and presentation formats using the same .Rmd file, under the constraint that the presentation output should be figures only.

I have many .Rmd files that need to be re-formatted depending on which output I need at any given time. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give an example of a document where the conversion is difficult.  Normally you just change which entry in the Knit menu in RStudio you click on.

Comment: You can specify multiple formats in the header block at the top of the `Rmd` file, with unique options for each. Then you can choose which version you want to knit. Figuring out a set of options that will only show figures in the presentation output might be its own question.

Answer (score -1):

An effective way could be the `output` tag of the YAML header of the Rmd file, based on which it generates PDF/PPT/Doc/HTML, etc. outputs.

In the top YAML part of Rmd file:

```
output: ioslides_presentation
```

for a presentation output.

Similarly, there are more formats described in the [documentation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-9.html).